# SQL Server 2008 Express doesn't see my Visual Studio 2008 Team System's SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-express

I want to install SQL Server 2008 express. I have already Visual Studio 2008 Team System with SP1.

VS in help > about shows me:

MVS version: 9.0.30729.1 SP
.NET Framework version: 3.5 SP1

but installator of SQL Server shows me that Visual Studio doesn't have SP1. Anyway I tricked up him by change in win registry HKLM > Software > Microsoft > DevDiv > VS > Servicing > 9.0 > IDE > 1033 value from RTM on SP1 and instalation runs. But during instalation error was occured about SP1 again. SQL Server was installed without SQL Managment. When I try install it I have allways the same error about SP1. I was install SP1 couple times with success but it does nothing. I was instal SQL Server SP1 also but it does nothing. Reinstall of VS 2008 and SP1 does nothing.

What can I do?

Thanks for any help,
Kamilos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete HKLM > Software > Microsoft > DevDiv > VS > Servicing > 9.0 > IDE > 1033 from registry was help.